# mysql query to get only posts in the same category and they have same tags-Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, select

In Wordpress how can write mysql query to get only posts in the same category and they have same tags
example I want all post that in the number categories 5,8,15,18 and they number tags 2,3,20,25
both, Number Of categories and number of tags have in the wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
How can write this select?

Answer (score 0):

The basic query that would get any combination of category/tag:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE 
category in (5,8,15,18)
AND tag in (2,3,20,25);
```

You can customize it more with a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE 
((category = 5 AND tag in (2,3,20,25))
OR (category = 8 AND tag in (2,3,20,25))
OR (category = 15 AND tag in (2,3,20,25))
OR (category = 18 AND tag in (2,3,20,25));
```

Comment: The above would return a post even if it only belongs to one of the categories and one of the tags.

Comment: Thank you.
but its example and I dont know how can select number of categories and number of tags because they have same filed name(term_taxonomy_id).